# Text Based Minesweeper in C

Tags: beginner, c, minesweeper

This is my first C program. The code works, however I'm not yet familiar with how to write *idiomatic* C. How should I improve this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define UNCLICKED 0
#define CLICKED 1
#define FLAGGED 2

#define NOT_BOMB 0
#define BOMB 1

struct piece {
    char user_state, game_state, value;
};

int generate_rand();
int valid(int, int);
void print_board(struct piece[8][8], int);
int click(struct piece[8][8], int, int);
int game_over(struct piece[8][8]);

int main() {
    struct piece board[8][8];

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            board[i][j].user_state = UNCLICKED;
            board[i][j].game_state = NOT_BOMB;
            board[i][j].value = 0;
        }
    }

    srand(time(0));

    int num_bombs = 10;

    while (num_bombs > 0) {

        int y, x;

        do {
            y = generate_rand();
            x = generate_rand();
        } while (board[y][x].game_state == BOMB);

        board[y][x].game_state = BOMB;

        int delta_row, delta_column;
        for (delta_row = -1; delta_row <= 1; delta_row++) {
            for (delta_column = -1; delta_column <= 1; delta_column++) {
                if (valid(y + delta_row, x + delta_column)) {
                    board[y + delta_row][x + delta_column].value++;
                }
            }
        }

        num_bombs--;
    }

    print_board(board, 1);

    while (1) {
        char row, column, move_type;
        printf("\nEnter a row: ");
        row = getchar() - 48;
        getchar();
        printf("Enter a column: ");
        column = getchar() - 48;
        getchar();

        if (!valid(row, column)) {
            printf("Location is not on board. Try again: \n");
            continue;
        }

        if (board[row][column].user_state == CLICKED) {
            printf("That square is already open. Try again: \n");
            continue;
        }

        printf("[C]lick or [F]lag? ");
        move_type = getchar();
        getchar();
        printf("\n");

        if (move_type == 'C') {
            if (click(board, row, column)) {
                printf("That was a bomb! \n");
                print_board(board, 0);
                break;
            }
        } else if (move_type == 'F') {
            if (board[row][column].user_state == CLICKED) {
                printf("That square is already open. Try again: \n");
                continue;
            } else {
                board[row][column].user_state = FLAGGED;
            }
        } else {
            printf("Enter either 'C' or 'F'. Try again: \n");
            continue;
        }

        if (game_over(board)) {
            printf("You win! \n");
            print_board(board, 0);
            break;
        } else {
            print_board(board, 1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int generate_rand() {
    return (rand() % 8);
}

int valid(int row, int column) {
    return row >= 0 && row < 8 && column >= 0 && column < 8;
}

void print_board(struct piece board[8][8], int in_game) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (in_game) {
                if (board[i][j].user_state == CLICKED) {
                    printf("%d ", board[i][j].value);
                } else if (board[i][j].user_state == FLAGGED) {
                    printf("F ");
                } else {
                    printf("- ");
                }
            } else {
                if (board[i][j].game_state == NOT_BOMB) {
                    if (board[i][j].user_state == FLAGGED) {
                        printf("X ");
                    } else {
                        printf("%d ", board[i][j].value);
                    }
                } else {
                    printf("B ");
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int click(struct piece board[8][8], int row, int column) {
    if (!valid(row, column) || board[row][column].game_state == BOMB || board[row][column].user_state == CLICKED) {
        return 1;
    }

    board[row][column].user_state = CLICKED;
    if (board[row][column].value == 0) {
        int i, j;
        for (i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
                click(board, row + i, column + j);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int game_over(struct piece board[8][8]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (board[i][j].game_state == NOT_BOMB && board[i][j].user_state == UNCLICKED) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Would it make sense to put some of the code in a separate header file, or is that over complicating things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that strikes me immediately is that we pass `struct piece board[8][8]` around quite a lot.  There's two things I would change there.  The first is to use a typedef (or perhaps a small struct) to save all that typing.  The other would be to give names to the dimensions.

```
#define BOARD_WIDTH  8
#define BOARD_HEIGHT 8

typedef struct piece game_board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];
```

If we want to build the game for a different height and width, then there will be only one place to change (once the loop bounds are adjusted to use the defined macros instead of literal `8`).  And we've made it easier if we ever want to transition to runtime-chosen board size in future (that's a more advanced exercise that you should try when you feel ready for it).

The typedef means that instead of writing out function arguments like

```
void print_board(const struct piece board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH], int in_game);
```

they can be shorter and clearer:

```
void print_board(const game_board board, int in_game);
```

---

There's some weaknesses here:

> ```
>     printf("\nEnter a row: ");
>     row = getchar() - 48;
>     getchar();
>     printf("Enter a column: ");
>     column = getchar() - 48;
>     getchar();
> ```

Remember that any call to `getchar()` can return `EOF`.  If that happens, we'll probably want to terminate the program, as we can't expect any useful input from that point onwards.

Secondly, the magic number `48` is specific to the character coding in use - we can make the program more portable by using `'0'` as is evidently intended.

It's also quite fragile - we're expecting a single character and newline, but users make mistakes and might enter multiple characters (and we'd probably want to allow that if we make the board bigger than 10✕10).

Thankfully, we have a better alternative to char-by-char input, and that's *formatted input* using `scanf()`.  That would look something like

```
    printf("\nEnter a row and column: ");
    while (scanf("%hhd%hhd", &row, &column) != 2) {
        if (feof(stdin)) {
            /* scanf can never succeed now */
            fputs("Input failure\n", stderr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        /* Discard any remaining input */
        scanf("%*[^\n]");   /* ignore errors here */
        printf("Invalid input.  Enter a row and column: ");
    }
```

That's not 100% robust, but it's an improvement.

---

A small fix: these function declarations should be *prototypes*, i.e. specify what arguments they take:

> ```
> int generate_rand();
>
> int main() {
> ```

The way we tell the compiler that they take no arguments at all (rather than unspecified arguments) is to write `void` between the parentheses:

```
int generate_rand(void);

int main(void) {
```

---

The structure is a bit unbalanced.  There are a few low-level functions, but most of the logic is in a huge `main()`.  Try dividing it into high-level functions - perhaps `initialise_board()` could be one of them?

---

There are more things that could be improved, but I hope this gives you some things to consider.

Comment: What does `typedef struct piece game_board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];` do?

Comment: @ap It creates a type that you can use and that reduces the amount of code necessary in function declarations.

Comment: @ap: Yes, as pacmaninbw says, it makes the code shorter, and clearer - see latest edit.

Comment: @ap see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/typedef and bookmark that site so you can easily look things up in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Some style suggestions:

1. Use enums instead of #defines.

   ```
   enum {
     state_UNCLICKED,
     state_CLICKED,
     state_FLAGGED
   } ;
   ```

Followed by `if (board[i][j].user_state == state_CLICKED)`

2. It's easier to understand structure definitions if each member is on its own line.

```
struct piece {
   char user_state;
   char game_state;
   char  value;
};
```

3. Generally it's nice to put argument names in function declarations.  Then readers don't need to jump to the implementation to find out what the arguments mean.
4. I might refactor

```
           board[i][j].user_state = UNCLICKED;
           board[i][j].game_state = NOT_BOMB;
           board[i][j].value = 0;
```

into a `board_square_init(board, i,j)` function.  I might also create a `square_place_bomb(board, i,j)` function that does the neighbor update.

5. It's odd that `click` returns `1` for several unrelated things: out of bounds, already clicked, and bomb.   You are getting away with it because you pre-test for clicked before calling this function, but it would be cleaner if you returned a different value for the different failures.  Maybe add `state_INVALID` to the enum in comment 1, and return a member of the enum.
6. Many people dislike globals in C, and there are some good reasons for that.  But unless you are planning on writing a program that manages multiple boards at once, you could just declare the single board once globally, and stop passing it to every single function.  You trade a potentially useful future capability of multiple board support for simpler code today.